# RestTemplate is Null in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring MVC application. Below is one class that has `RestTemplate` and calling external service, it's working fine.

We migrated Spring MVC (war) to Spring Boot 1.5.7 (jar). With migration, below is giving `NullPointerException` for `restTemplate`. I have added a print statement and `restTemplate` is `null`.
I have added `@Bean` with `getRestTemplate()`, but that's still giving same error.

```
@Service
Class Impl{

   @Autowired
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

   public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
       return restTemplate;
   }

   public void setRestTemplate(final RestTemplate restTemplate) {
       this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
   }

}
```

How do I fix this ? Why is it working with Spring MVC and not with Spring Boot?

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml`? Thanks.

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` if a dependency cannot be fulfilled your application wouldn't start. If it is null you are creating an instance of your `Impl` yourself. See https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null/

Comment: My pom.xml is  here-   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>             I do have other non spring dependencies as well in pom.xml